# Installing Ubuntu over elementary os

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, elementary

Similar to this questions were asked in this community many times, but none of them could help me. I need to make sure.

I currently have installed elementary OS 0.3.2 and I want to switch to Ubuntu 16 without losing my /home files.

So I created a USB stick contains Ubuntu and booted to live and then Ubuntu installation, chose "Something else" and now I see my partitions. As far as I know I must select the partition with "elementary OS 0.3.2" description to install Ubuntu over elementary.

Now my question is: Is there anything else should I do to not to lose my /home data?

Comment: Do you have `/home` on a separate partition?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes I do, as mentioned in question, too.

Comment: It doesn't actually say that `/home` is on a separate partition anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu on your Elementary `/` partition and select the Elemantary `/home` as your Ubuntu `/home`.

The data on the `/home` will not be deleted.

You need to take in account that user specific settings will stay as well. That may cause some conflicts with the new DE.

A better way is to create a new user in Ubuntu and transfer files to the new user home directory. Then delete the old user. That will get all settings cleaned.

Comment: The only confusion thing here for me is that how can I choose a specific partition for /home without formatting it?

Comment: When you run the installer and select "Something else", the installer will show you the existing partitions, you will be able to select them. And there is a checkbox to format or not. You need to check the format option for `/` and leave it blank for `/home`.

Comment: and then Ubuntu detects automatically that should mount /home at that partition?

Comment: If you tell the installer to use this partition as `/home`, then it will be mounted and used as `/home`.

Comment: @Pilot61 My question now is how to tell the installer that?

Comment: At the same screen where you choose partitions to install,format or not, you can set mount points.